# Nested component not loading in VueJS 3

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

I'm working on VueJS 3, where I've created my own components. Scenario is like below:

1. Already I have created a button component, and it's working perfectly independently.
2. I've created another datatable component which also working fine independently.

But the problem is: whenever I include or call my button component inside datatable component, everything working fine except button component and raised Vue warning like below:

> VUE warning: "runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6584 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: q-button
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement."

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Update question with your codes here. That's helpful to understand this issue for us.

Comment: Without code it is hard to write an answer, but it might be that you need to reference the button component within the datatable component.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by using `<slot name="add-items-actions"></slot>`
in my datatable( parent component ) and in child component I passed below code:

```
<template #add-items-actions class="mb-3">
    <router-link class="text-muted" to="/organization/service-area-add">
       <q-button class="d-none d-sm-block" icon="i-Add">Add service area</q-button>
    </router-link>
</template>
```

After that no error is raised and button component loaded correctly. Thanks all for giving a try.